# Adding flake8 to a codebase that is not a compliance with flake8 , using GitHub and GitHub actions

Tags: python-3.x, github, continuous-integration, devops, github-actions

I have a codebase that is not in compliance with flake8. The CI/CD pipeline uses GitHub/GitHub actions. I would like to start adding python flake8 ( to check for complexity, errors and code smells). How to accomplish this task? What details should I have into account?

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this package - [flakehell](https://flakehell.readthedocs.io/commands/baseline.html). It allows to ignore current flake errors, and it will lint only the new ones.